# Como adicionar anuncio no app?

Tags: android, xml

Estou utilizando este código:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Inicialização:

```
// Consultar o AdView como um recurso e carregar uma solicitação.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Porém fica com erro:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 'com.teste.teste1'   activity_teste.xml /Teste/res/layout    line 120    Android AAPT Problem

este erro já arrumei, meu código esta igualzinho o citado porém no Graphical Layout aonde está o BANNER esta escrito em vermelho

> XML Required attribute " adSize " was missing

Comment: O erro diz que você não definiu o atributo `loadAdOnCreate` no seu `AdView`

Comment: e como defini esse atributo se você pode me ajudar

Comment: Poderia colocar o código de inicialização?

Comment: @Wakim de uma olhada na minha edição

Comment: Você declarou o `namespace` **ads** em algum lugar?

Comment: nao endedi sua pergunta

Comment: Ele quis dizer se declarou: `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` em algum lugar acima do `AdView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta remover as linhas `android:padding.......` ai funcionou certinho.